# What paniers' rack for my bike?

Tags: rack, specialized-bikes

I own a Specialized Diverge E5 gravel bike and want to mount a rack on it.

The bike unfortunately only has mounting points on the rear dropout, not on the seatstays unlike many other bikes. Apparently I can buy a sort of seatpost connector which will allow me to get those 2 extra attaching points (something like [this](https://www.certini.co.uk/components/service-parts/specialized-s204700001-stc-my21-diverge-308-alloy-rack-compatible--black__70363))

I'm still unsure how to pick the rack though. Say if I were to buy this (which looks pretty standard):
[image]

- If the thru-axle width on my bike is 142mm, I assume this mean I'm within the maximum width of 160mm so that's OK?
- How do I make sure it won't touch the disk brakes? For this product in particular the vendor specified "Compatibility with disc brakes must be checked in each individual case!"
- Would the mounting stays reach my seatpost connector? If this is designed to be attached to the seatstays, this might not reach the seatpost

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> If the thru-axle width on my bike is 142mm, I assume this mean I'm within the maximum width of 160mm so that's OK?

Not necessarily. That’s 160mm max inner distance between the pannier mounts. 142mm is between the inner surface of the dropouts which gives you a max of 9mm leeway on both sides. Grab a ruler and measure between the mount bolts to be sure.

> How do I make sure it won't touch the disk brakes? For this product in particular the vendor specified "Compatibility with disc brakes must be checked in each individual case!"

> Would the mounting stays reach my seatpost connector? If this is designed to be attached to the seatstays, this might not reach the seatpost

If the product has a measurement diagram make a mock out of cardboard to give you an idea of whether it’s going to foul the rotor or calliper and if the stays will reach your seat connector.